# Is it necessary the two curves are crossing each other if I want to solve two equations with two unknown paramters?

Tags: math, mathematical-optimization, curve-fitting

I have two curves as show in this figure:

[image]

I have two equations of these curves with two unknown parameters, but I want to know is it necessary for these two curves to cross each other to be solved? or it is not necessary to be crossed? Because I want to publish it in my work and I want to know the right before I do it.

Comment: Note: These equations are exponential equations (non-linear), and  I solved it in matlab, and I got the results. But I am worried if they must cross each other to be accepted!

Comment: This question seems to be off-topic because it's about math, not programming.  You might get help on Math.SE.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is concerned with mathematics, not programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two curves need to intersect to find an unique solution where both curve equations hold true. If they intersect at more than 1 point, there exists that many unique solutions, as the number of intersections.

When the two curves do not meet, then the system is does not have any solution. 
http://www.montereyinstitute.org/courses/DevelopmentalMath/COURSE_TEXT2_RESOURCE/U14_L1_T1_text_final.html

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: yes. 
Longer answer: Solving two equations `f(x)` and `g(x)` for two unknowns is the same as solving `f(x) = g(x)`. The only time that those are equal is at their intersection(s).